# restrict onbeforeunload to close event only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to fire an ajax only when user close the browser window or webpage but not on the following.

1. page redirection by link navigation,form submission or window.location function
2. <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL+F5</kbd> press
3. <kbd>CTRL+R</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+R</kbd> press
4. When click on reload button of the browser focus on URL typing box and press enter

Can anyone help me in this issue.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question does not meet the [established criteria for quality](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in StackOverflow. See what you should [avoid asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). You need to provide details on what you have tried. Show us your code and someone will help you make it work. Thanks

Comment: _I want to fire an ajax only...._ where this comes from, never heard of it?